# Chromedriver error on Django DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, digital-ocean

I'm currently developping a web app using django and the App platform on digitalocean.
My web app uses selenium and chromedriver, I have found a way to install chromedriver using python libs such as chromedriver_binary on pip but the app can't open it and throws me an error :

```
Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

This error most likely means that some dependencies and libs are not available and leads to the script crashing.

Here's my current code inside views.py :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chromium.options import ChromiumOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def get_webdriver(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

Is there a way (maybe using another lib, or a whole other solution) to deploy chromedriver on this django app?

EDIT 1 :

Seems like the app does find the chromedriver, I can print it through the code below :

```
def get_webdriver(url):
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    driver_path = chromedriver_binary.chromedriver_filename
    print("Driver's path : ", driver_path)
    ser = Service(driver_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

The print returns me :

```
/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver_binary/chromedriver
```

It really seems like some libraries or dependencies are missing but I don't know how to install them on this app platform.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted arguments unless any specific requirement:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

and keep only the intended one:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

and execute your test.

Comment: I have removed all options and only kept the headless one as follows : 

def get_webdriver(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver

But still gets the same error : 

Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127